# Simple 2D gravity with pygame; Value Guidelines?

Tags: python, pygame, physics, gravity

I am trying to simulate gravity in a simple 2D window using pygame. It's very simple stuff (a dot rising and falling again) and I understand the mechanics, i.e. speed as a vector and the y portion being consistently diminished by a value g representing gravity during each run through the mainloop and the subsequent update of the position of the dot.


It's all working fine, but I am having trouble choosing the correct values to be inserted. It is all trial and error at the moment. **Is there a good rule of thumb on how to determine which numbers to use, to achieve a semi-realistic looking trajectory?**

I inserted a minimal example below, with the following values important to my question:

```
window = (640, 480) # pixels
initial_speed = 20 # pixels per update along the y axis
gravity = 0.4 # deduction on initial_speed per update
```

Now, why do these numbers happen to make the illusion work? I tried first to use formulae I learnt in physics class years and years ago, but, with or without unit conversions, the simulation was just not right. Most of the time, I didn't even see the ball, yet the above values, found through trial and error work.

Thanks for all your help in advance. If you need more information, just post a comment and I will try to oblige.

Here is the minimal example. Note the vector2D library was conveniently borrowed from the pygame website ([follow this link](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/2DVectorClass))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from vector2D import Vec2d

pygame.init()

GRAVITY = 0.4

class Dot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, img_file, init_position, init_direction, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen

        self.speed = Vec2d(speed)

        self.base_image = pygame.image.load(img_file).convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.base_image
        # A vector specifying the Dot's position on the screen
        self.pos = Vec2d(init_position)

        # The direction is a normalized vector
        self.direction = Vec2d(init_direction).normalized()

    def blitme(self):
        """ Blit the Dot onto the screen that was provided in
            the constructor.
        """
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.pos)

    def update(self):
        self.speed.y -= GRAVITY

        displacement = Vec2d(
            self.direction.x * self.speed.x,
            self.direction.y * self.speed.y
        )
        self.pos += displacement

def main():
    DIMENSION = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640, 480
    BG_COLOUR = 0,0,0

    # Creating the screen
    window = screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), 0, 32)
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    dot = Dot(screen, "my/path/to/dot.jpg", (180, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
                      (0, -1), (0, 20))

    mainloop = True
    while mainloop:
        # Limit frame speed to 50 FPS
        time_passed = clock.tick(50)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mainloop = False

        # Redraw the background
        screen.fill(BG_COLOUR)

        dot.update()
        dot.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Pick a unit you want a pixel to represent, then take real values for these things and plug them in.

Comment: @Lattyware: I tried that, but as I mentioned very briefly, if I used numbers such g = 9.81 (or 10 for sake easiness), very little of the calculations actually happen inside that window. I tried to assign things such as 50px correspond to 1m etc. but the conversions make it even worse. What do you suggest to circumvent that problem? Thanks for your help btw. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> def update(self):
>
> ```
>    self.speed.y -= GRAVITY
>
>    displacement = Vec2d(
>         self.direction.x * self.speed.x,
>         self.direction.y * self.speed.y
>     )
>     self.pos += displacement
> ```

You call Dot.update() 50 times every second. The equation you're using,

```
delta v_y = - g #* (1 second)
```

represents the change in velocity **every second**, but it gets called 50 times every second. This means your velocities will lose `50*GRAVITY m/s` ever second and this is why you are forced to make your gravity so weak.

So, I would recommend adding `time_passed` as an argument for `Dot.update`, and change the speed changing statement to

```
def update(self, time_passed):
    self.speed.y -= GRAVITY * time_passed/1000. #time converted from millisecond to seconds
```

This will make the units more intuitive. Switch `GRAVITY` back to 10 and use realistic velocities.

**EDIT:**

Additionally, the displacement vector also needs to contain time, or else the displacement will depend on FPS. If you have `x` frames per second, then each update occurs after `t = 1000/x` milliseconds. This is the amount of time Dot spends "moving" in each update. Think about how we approximate Dot's motion; it gets an update, calculates its new velocity and travels at that speed for `t` seconds. However, in your implementation, the displacement vector is independent of time. Change the update method to be something like:

```
def update(self, time):
    time /= 1000.
    self.speed.y -= GRAVITY * time

    displacement = Vec2d(
        self.direction.x * self.speed.x * time,
        self.direction.y * self.speed.y * time
    )
    self.pos += displacement
```

Now, according to kinematics, we'll get something like

```
max height = v0**2 / 2g
```

so initial velocities of 10-20m/s will only produce max heights of 5-20m. If you don't want to work with velocities of 50-200m/s, then you could add a scaling factor in the displacement vector, something like

```
    displacement = Vec2d(
        self.direction.x * self.speed.x * time * scaling_factor,
        self.direction.y * self.speed.y * time * scaling_factor
    )
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! This makes a lot of sense now. One of those (facepalm) moments ;). One thing I noticed, however, is that on changing the amount of frames per second, there is a difference on how high Dot rises toward the ceiling (50: almost touches the top; 25: just below half the height of the window; 10: not even bottom third before descent). How would I adjust this to have the distance travelled independent from the Frames per second?

Comment: Fantastic! With the scaling_factor you even answered a question, I was working on, but haven't asked ;) Great stuff! Game Physics 101. Thanks a lot!